# Javascript reload page in a closure/anon function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, reload

I am using jQuery to animate some DOM elements, but I want the page to reload when the animations are complete, so I tried this:

```
function childDisablePopup()
{
    $("#popup2",window.parent.document).animate({
        width: "0px",
        marginLeft: 0
    }, "fast",
    function()
    {
        $("#popup2",window.parent.document).animate({
            height: "0px",
            marginTop: 0
        }, "fast",
        function()
        {
            $("#backgroundPopup",window.parent.document).fadeOut("fast",
                function()
                {
                    $("#popup2",window.parent.document).remove();
                    window.location.reload(true);
                });
        });
    });
}
```

However, when the animation completes, instead of the page reloading, I get this error:

> uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMLocation.reload]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: etc...]

What's going on? Can page reloads not be put in a function(){} closure?

Note: Browser: firefox 3.6.8.

Audience browsers: firefox 3+, chrome, safari 5+

Note: I also tried `window.location.reload(true);` which returned the same error, and I tried `window.location.href=window.location.href` which returned:

> uncaught exception: [Exception...
>   "Component returned failure code:
>   0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER)
>   [nsIDOMLocation.href]" nsresult:
>   "0x80004003
>   (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER)" location:
>   "JS frame :: etc...]

Comment: `window.location.href` might not accept assignment. Try `window.location.replace(window.location.href);`?  I'm starting to lean towards my initial thought which was that this has more to do with trying to interact with the DOM of the parent window...  Frankly I'm stumped.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the exception. (I'm using Firefox 3.6.8 as well.) Except I didn't make use of `window.parent.document` in the selectors, so it could either be that or something elsewhere in your script.

Comment: Ok this is weird, I can't even do an `alert(window.location.href)` without it throwing the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. What I was doing is opening up an iframe, and then removing it. I wanted to trigger the page reload on iframe removal, however, the script is being run from WITHIN the iframe, so when the iframe no longer exists, the script no longer has a context to run from. In essence, I can't call window.location when window doesn't even exist! However, window.parent.location also doesn't work since once the iframe disappears, I'm effectively calling null.parent, which doesn't exist either.

Hahaha, I guess I might have to change up the design a bit. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

`window.location.reload()` doesn't take any arguments, and unlike calling a JavaScript function, when calling a browser API function the browser is very strict about the number of arguments that can/must be passed to the function.

**EDIT:** Thanks to OP for pointing this out, Firefox at least allows one parameter to be passed to reload(). (see http://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location)

Comment: Actually, according to the MDC: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location

reload() takes 1 parameter, forceget, if set to true, it forces a request to the server instead of simply reloading from browser cache.

Comment: Good call, my goto JS reference has failed me. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Comment: Hmm, in that case the forceget parameter might be a firefox only implementation. the window.location object is not part of ECMA's javascript specifications, so I guess browser dependent implementations is likely. I can't seem to find webkit's javascript documentation however.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem.
I solved this by calling the code only when the page was loaded.
For me both the below scripts worked.

```
window.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", doStuff, false);
```

and

```
window.addEventListener ("load", doStuff, false);
```

If both works for you prefer the first.